# CUPS referencing old Gutenprint version

Tags: raspbian, cups

I am trying to get the new Gutenprint 5.2.10 driver to work with CUPS 2.0.0 in my Rasberry Pi, using Raspbian8. I'm still kind of new to the Linux environment so please bear with me if I use the wrong terms.

I installed CUPS 1.5.3 using `sudo apt-get install cups` unknowingly that it would install an older version. So I subsequently removed it through package manager and installed CUPS 2.0.0.

However, removing CUPS 1.5.3 did not remove the older Gutenprint 5.2.9 driver. Even after removing the Gutenprint 5.2.9 package files in package manager, leaving only Gutenprint 5.2.10 package files, CUPS 2.0.0 is still not refereing the package files.

I know this because I do not see the printer model in the list in CUPS browser interface when adding a new printer.

I did however, manage to get it working in my Ubuntu machine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get CUPS to use Gutenprint 5.2.10?

Comment: Which version of Raspbian are you using?  cat /etc/os-release. On jessie the driver is 5.2.10. printer-driver-gutenprint (5.2.10-3+b2 Raspbian:testing [armhf])

Comment: @joan Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: You could update to jessie.  That would give you 5.2.10.  However jessie is the testing distribution so other things might be broken (wheezy is the current stable distribution).

Comment: @joan ah alright. so there is no way to configure CUPS manually in wheezy to use gutenprint 5.2.10?

Comment: I don't know.  I haven't tried. It would depend on how many packages would need to be updated to support 5.2.10.  If something like a core library needs to be upgraded it could break other packages within wheezy.  The latest version of CUPS supported by Debian is 1.7.5-7.  CUPS 2.0.0 seems to be bleeding edge.

Comment: @joan ah thanks man. You just made it a whole lot clearer for me why gutenprint 5.2.10 was not working. great help!